# ReactJS & ElectronJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

Hello guys I was hoping to find help here since I'm very new to coding in reactjs and electron.

Im trying to put a searchbar between the tabs and content like on chrome I use Antd

The code of the Tabs, I don't know where I need to add my searchbar to get it under the tabs and over the content as shown in the picture:

Help much appreciated :)

```
import { Tabs, Input, Space } from 'antd';
import React from 'react';
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';
import '../../index.css';
import App from '../../App';
import { AudioOutlined } from '@ant-design/icons';
const { Search } = Input;

const suffix = (
  <AudioOutlined
    style={{
      fontSize: 16,
      color: '#1890ff',
    }}
  />
);

const onSearch = value => console.log(value);

const { TabPane } = Tabs;

const initialPanes = [
  { title: 'Tab 1', content: 'Content of Tab 1', key: '1' },
//  { title: 'Tab 2', content: 'Content of Tab 2', key: '2' },
//  {
//    title: 'Tab 3',
//    content: 'Content of Tab 3',
//    key: '3',
//    closable: false,
//  },
];

class Demo extends React.Component {
  newTabIndex = 0;

  state = {
    activeKey: initialPanes[0].key,
    panes: initialPanes,
  };

  onChange = activeKey => {
    this.setState({ activeKey });
  };

  onEdit = (targetKey, action) => {
    this[action](targetKey);
  };

  add = () => {
    const { panes } = this.state;
    const activeKey = `newTab${this.newTabIndex++}`;
    const newPanes = [...panes];
    newPanes.push({ title: 'New Tab', content: 'Content of new Tab', key: activeKey });
    this.setState({
      panes: newPanes,
      activeKey,
    });
  };

  remove = targetKey => {
    const { panes, activeKey } = this.state;
    let newActiveKey = activeKey;
    let lastIndex;
    panes.forEach((pane, i) => {
      if (pane.key === targetKey) {
        lastIndex = i - 1;
      }
    });
    const newPanes = panes.filter(pane => pane.key !== targetKey);
    if (newPanes.length && newActiveKey === targetKey) {
      if (lastIndex >= 0) {
        newActiveKey = newPanes[lastIndex].key;
      } else {
        newActiveKey = newPanes[0].key;
      }
    }
    this.setState({
      panes: newPanes,
      activeKey: newActiveKey,
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { panes, activeKey } = this.state;
    return (
      <Tabs
        type="editable-card"
        onChange={this.onChange}
        activeKey={activeKey}
        onEdit={this.onEdit}
      >
        {panes.map(pane => (
          <TabPane tab={pane.title} key={pane.key} closable={pane.closable}>
            {pane.content}
          </TabPane>
        ))}
      </Tabs>
    );
  }
}
export { Demo };
```

Comment: Just wrap the tabs in some parent div and put your search bar below the <Tabs/> ? I'm not sure to understand your question.

Comment: @Peterrabbit That wouldn't work adding a <div> under the 

      <Tabs
        type="editable-card"
        onChange={this.onChange}
        activeKey={activeKey}
        onEdit={this.onEdit}
      >
I have tried things like that.
And I want the search bar like on chrome you know where we have the tabs over and content under. But thanks for trying to come up with a solution

Comment: Oh so you are talking about the window toolbar maybe, to set up a menu ? You wont do that with React in Electron, This is handlef by the Electron Menu class. Anyway your question is not very clear, I think you'll get more help if you are more specific about what exactely you want to do (from a coding point o view) , what you tried and why it doesn't work.

Comment: Oh or maybe you were talking about the actual web pages tabs ? Sorry I'm confused.